# Argparse: defaults from file

Tags: python, argparse, configparser

I have a Python script which takes a lot of arguments.
I currently use a `configuration.ini` file (read using `configparser`), but would like to allow the user to override specific arguments using command line.
If I'd only have had two arguments I'd have used something like:

```
if not arg1:
    arg1 = config[section]['arg1']
```

But I don't want to do that for 30 arguments.
Any easy way to take optional arguments from cmd line, and default to the `config` file?

Comment: You should have a look at [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects), there's even an example quite close to what you want.

Comment: Use `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default, to keep arguments out of the namespace when no value is provided.  Then use `update` to add `vars(args)` entries to a dictionary containing the `config` values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following, using [dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
import argparse
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
defaults = config['default']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', dest='arg1')
parser.add_argument('-b', dest='arg2')
parser.add_argument('-c', dest='arg3')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

result = dict(defaults)
result.update({k: v for k, v in args.items() if v is not None})  # Update if v is not None
```

With this example of ini file:

```
[default]
arg1=val1
arg2=val2
arg3=val3
```

and

```
python myargparser.py -a "test"
```

`result` would contain:

```
{'arg1': 'test', 'arg2': 'val2', 'arg3': 'val3'}
```

Comment: With `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` you won't need the `None` filter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects) from the `collections` module.

From the doc:

> A ChainMap groups multiple dicts or
>   other mappings together to create a single, updateable view. [...]
>
> Lookups search the underlying mappings successively until a key is
>   found.  [...]

So, you could create

- a `config` dict containing the key-value pairs from your config file,
- a `cmd_line_args` dict containing the ones given on the command line

Then, create a ChainMap:

```
from collections import ChainMap
combined = ChainMap(cmd_line_args, config)
```

When you access `combined['arg1']`, arg1 will first be looked up in the `cmd_line_args` dict, and if it isn't found there, `config[arg1]` will be returned.
You can chain as many dicts as you wish, which lets you combine as many levels of defaults as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parser.set_defaults()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) to do a bulk override of defaults (so that non-entered arguments get populated from the config).  Conveniently, this allows the argparse argument default field to specify a last-resort default for the case where the argument was not provided on the commandline nor in the config.  However, the arguments still need to be added to the parser somehow so that the parser is willing to recognize them.  Mostly, `set_defaults()` is useful if you already have an argparse parser set up, but you just want to override the defaults to come from the config if they aren't specified on the commandline:

```py
import argparse

config = dict(
    a=11,
    b=13,
    c=19
)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#  add arguments to parser ...
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-c', type=int)

parser.set_defaults(**config)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

If you weren't planning on already having a parser set up with all available parameters, then you could alternatively use your config to set one up (given the defaults directly for each argument, so no need to do the additional `set_defaults()` step:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
config = dict(
    a=11,
    b=13,
    c=19
)

for key, value in config.items():
    parser.add_argument(f'-{key}', default=value, type=type(value))

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```