# How to call input parameters into another python file using argparse?

Tags: python, user-input, argparse

I have the following files in a python pipeline

```
#in_para.py

nx = 31
c = 1
```

```
#solver.py
import numpy
import os   

def simple(output):
    ny = nx + 5
    c_2 = c + 2
    with open(os.path.join(output, 'Output.txt'), 'w') as f:
         print("Hello stackoverflow!", file=f)
         print("I have a question.", file=f)
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    simple()
```

```
#main.py 

import os
import numpy
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk',type=str, help='Choose arg')
    parser.add_argument('-O','--output',type=str, default="./Output", help=' Provide the output Directory')

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
 
    output = args['output']
    if not os.path.exists(output):
        os.makedirs(output)

    if args['Chk'] == 'compo1':
        simple(output)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to call the input file `in_para.py` through command line argument such that

```
python3 main.py -I in_para -C compo1 -O Ouput_dir
```

gives me the desired output:

```
this is a simple test 36
this is a simple test2 3
```

I know  if I do `from in_para import *` it will solve the problem (in a different manner), but I would like to call the input parameters from the command line as a positional argument and pass it on to `solver.py`. I haven't been able to find an example in the documentation similar to above task. Besides, the above is just an example, `in_para.py` and `solver.py` has several input parameters and several lines of code, so I dont want the user of `main.py` to go into either file and modify it.

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars

Comment: Or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538581/argparse-defaults-from-file

Comment: @CarlosHorn its not about having large set of input parameters, I would like to import it via an input file using argparse in `main.py` and pass it on to the `solver.py`

Comment: You could also make your function in `solver.py` explicit and pass the input arguments like `def simple(nx, c)` this will allow you to implement any logic on providing the input, e.g. parse a yaml file which was given as command line argument.

Comment: Or is it important that the input file is a python file, e.g. because some parameters are computed there?

Comment: @CarlosHorn input file will just have the parameters, non of them are computed there. it can be any file extension.

Comment: You are proposing to store configuration parameters as Python code. That is a bad idea. You're not writing Lua: there are better ways to do it. Look at `configparser` and `json` for more robust techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Change the implementation in `solver.py`

```
def simple(nx, c, output):  # provide parameters as function arguments
    ny = nx + 5
    c_2 = c + 2
    print("this is a simple test", ny)
    print("this is a simple test2", c_2)
    with open(os.path.join(output, 'Output.txt'), 'w') as f:
        print("Hello stackoverflow!", file=f)
        print("I have a question.", file=f)
```

In the main parse the parameters file

```
...  # other imports
import json

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk', type=str, help='Choose arg')
    parser.add_argument('-I','--input', type=argparse.FileType("r"), help='Input parameters')
    parser.add_argument('-O','--output', type=str, help='output dir')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    output = args.output
    # implement any way of parsing the input file, e.g. a json file
    params = json.load(args.input)
    
    ...  # do something else with the arguments
 
    if args.Chk == 'compo1':
        simple(output=output, **params)

...  # further code lines
```

Your inputs file would look like

```
{"nx": 31, "c": 1}
```

**Comment on edit:**

Either you use `args = vars(parser.parse_args())` which results in a dictionary or you just use the `args = parser.parse_args()` to select arguments by attribute. In your original post you used the first approach which I adopted in the first answer. However, I would prefer not using `vars`.
Note, that the code snippet to create the directory does not add value to the actual question of the post, so I removed it to avoid any distraction and added some placeholder instead.

Comment: Note, this implementation uses a `json` file, but as @BoarGules suggested, you could also use an ini file parsed with `configparser` or even write your own parser (not recommended if json or ini files can do the job) another popular format is yaml, which is more focused on human readable than json, but it is not part of the standard  python library.

Comment: May I know why you have modified the `solver.py` ?

Comment: Because the function `simple` should receive the parameters as argument instead of getting them from the global namespace.

Comment: actually there shouldnt be nx in `solver.py` in the first place. that is a typo

Comment: In any case, the point is to provide parameters as input arguments, so you have more flexibility on where you get them from. I would not recommend to work with globals here.

Comment: In other words, provide input to your functions as input arguments, this is what line number 2 in https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python is all about.

Comment: Does the answer help you? Or do you really need a solution which dynamically sets the variables in the module namespace (like `from in_para import *`)?

Comment: I've got some idea, but I actually have `simple(output)` to save the output from `simple` function at a disired dir. so `simple(**params)` doesnt really work completely.  My post is updated

Comment: This is not a contradiction to the given answer, output would just be another argument of simple, note that `simple(**params)` is just a short hand for `simple(nx=params["nx"], c=params["c"], ...adding other keys in params)`, so you could easily add the output argument to the json file.